# Retrieve most recent copy of record in DynamoDB after ConditionalCheckFailedException occurs

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm updating a record in DynamoDB and when a ConditionalCheckFailedException occurs, I'm wondering if I could get a new copy of that record. A lot of times when a ConditionalCheckFailedException occurs it's because I don't have the most recent copy of a record and thus I have to go back to DynamoDB to get the most recent copy. It would be nice if I could see that the ConditionExpression failed and get the most recent copy of the record all in one request. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it in one DynamoDB request. A ConditionalCheckFailedException results in an error response, and that won't include any other information other than the error.

You would have to catch the exception from your update, inspect the exception for ConditionalCheckFailed and then do your logic to get the most recent copy. So it is probably at least 2 Dynamo requests